# Change alignment of particular column - Gridview

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview whose items should be left aligned and I have written the code as below. Now I have a column for serial number. Only this column should be center aligned. How can I achieve this? I have done like below. But serial number column is always center aligned.
In short, The first column items of gridview should be center aligned. And the remaining columns should be left aligned.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
 CssClass="gridview_alter"  GridLines="Both"  HorizontalAlign="Right"  CellPadding="4" 
 CellSpacing="2" HeaderStyle-Height="60px" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
 HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Larger" Caption="Information" CaptionAlign="Top"          
 OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">             
            <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SNo"><ItemTemplate >
        <asp:Label ID="lblSRNO" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <HeaderStyle  Width="20px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>                                          
        <asp:BoundField DataField="count" HeaderText="Total" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField> 
            </Columns> 
 </asp:GridView>


protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView2.Columns[0].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;//serialnum
}

.gridview_alter {
width: 85%;
font-family: Arial !important;
border: 2px solid #d7dedb;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
 .gridview_alter th {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
  .gridview_alter td {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your remaining two columns [ name, count ], you should also add the `ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign` and `HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign` property as:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" 
        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" .... />
```

There are ways to do this programmmatically also by catching the RowDataBound event of gridview. I believe the markups should be just fine for setting the alignments.